# Is there a word for when suffixes are overly co-opted into new words?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

For example:

Alcoholic -- Alcohol means... well, alcohol. The suffix "-ic" [means "of or pertaining to"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ic)

Chocoholic -- Choco: a shortened form of "chocolate". The suffix "-holic" seemingly means "addicted to", though the suffix "-ic" is all that is required to denote this according to the previous example.

Is there an etymological term for this "suffix merging" that occurs? (bonus points for finding more examples of this)

#### Edit for Clarity

---

Here's an article from [grammarist](https://grammarist.com/suffix/aholic-oholic-and-holic/) describing this in more detail. "Alcoholic" was coined as a combination of "alcohol" and "-ic". Then, in the 20th century, the suffix "-holic" took on the meaning of "addicted to". E.g., "shopaholic", "workaholic", "golfaholic", etc.

Is there a word for when suffixes merge into words they are modifying in this manner?

#### Edit #2

Another example: helicopter comes from the greek “helix” or spiral, and “pter” or “flying” yet “-copter” is the suffix used for spinning blade flying things like “quadcopter”. Of course “quadpter” doesn’t really make sense in English, but I’m interested in a term to describe the combination of “helix” and “pter” becoming a new suffix

Comment: What do you mean by “etymological term”?

Comment: What do you mean by "suffix merging"? The **noun** *alcoholic* has a different meaning from the **adjective** *alcoholic*, so your meaning of *-ic* is suspect here. \[I suspect the actual answer is something like *production,* from *productive* — see [Lexico 1.4](https://www.lexico.com/definition/productive) — but *production* seems to be rather awkward.\]

Comment: The word [*ic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/IC) is a word that's used as a suffix; it's *purpose* is to use it grammatically. There is no such thing as its being "overly co-opted into new words." That's how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree, "-ic" is being used correctly. But the "-hol-" preceding it is what is being coopted in my example.

Comment: @Zaya Except that *alcoholic* is a combination of (1) *alcohol* and (2) *ic*; *hol* isn't being added in. With *chocoholic* however, we see (1) a shortened version of *chocolate*, (2) [*hol*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hol-), which is defined as a "combining form," and (3) *ic* again. (It's not actually the suffix "holic.") The formation of *alcoholic* seems expected. On the other hand, since neither *chocolateic* nor *chocolitic* would appear reasonable to me (simply based on words I'm familiar with), there was that shortening and use of the intermediary combining word.

Comment: @Zaya A literal translation would be "the character (ic) of being totally (hol) chocolate (choco)."

Comment: [linguistics.se] would probably be a better place to ask this

Comment: [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/what-is-the-consensus-on-how-words-are-formed-across-cultures-generally/34766#34766) at that site uses the term "prosody analogy"

Comment: It's probably also related to the use of the *-gate* suffix to refer to any scandal, by extension from Watergate.

Comment: So, the question asks whether there is a name for the linguistic phenomenon in which (1) the ending of some word starts being used as a suffix, (2) the meaning of the suffix is derived from that word, and (3) the meaning of the suffix could never be discerned apart from its association with that word. Is this a fair reformulation? (The word *merging* in the current formulation of the question may be confusing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word

Common hybrids
The most common form of hybrid word in English combines Latin and Greek parts. Since many prefixes and suffixes in English are of Latin or Greek etymology, it is straightforward to add a prefix or suffix from one language to an English word that comes from a different language, thus creating a hybrid word.

Hybridisms were formerly often considered to be barbarisms.

Chocoholic – a portmanteau of "chocolate" (from the Nahuatl xocolātl/chocolātl) and "alcoholic", which itself was formed from the Arabic اَلْكُحُول (al-kuḥūl) "alcohol" and the French adjectival suffix -ic

Mattergy – from the Latin materia ("material") and the Greek ἐνέργεια (energeia, "energy"): a "word for interchangeable matter and energy"[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opcfV.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzmTj.png) Adjectival form: "matergetic".

---

The Free Dictionary

sophomoric - Includes the roots soph-, "wise," and moros, "fool"—so the contrast between wisdom and ignorance is built right into the word.

---

[Cambridge History of English Language Vol 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=NxHuNOvwt7wC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=suffix%20combinations,%20chocoholic&source=bl&ots=_sjfnOIkj6&sig=ACfU3U3Y5hFujVtbH6ZUOf8MzVeaNlDaPg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA4va1wIrpAhXmmHIEHRB7AD4Q6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=suffix%20combinations%2C%20chocoholic&f=false)

**The Cambridge History of the English Language, Volume 4**
edited by Richard M. Hogg, Norman Francis Blake, Suzanne Romaine, Roger Lass, R. W. Burchfield

Affixing and Blending (partial snatches) p. 76

[image: Understanding Language Change]

**EDIT:**

Understanding Language Change
By Kate Burridge, Alexander Bergs - no page #, but identified by "2.1.12"

[image: About helicopter origin]

Comment: This may also be interesting to OP:  https://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200307242

Comment: These particular words may be hybrid words, but that is incidental to what the OP is concerned with: a part of a word becoming a suffix.